# How validate input and output of embed video field

Tags: wordpress

I use CMB2 — WordPress Plugins to create Custom Metaboxes. I have a textarea for embeding video. I need to validate the field in right way both on input and output.

```
$cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'            => $prefix . 'video_box',
    'title'         => __( 'Video - Embeded from YouTube or Vimeo', 'ttt' ),
    'object_types'  => array( 'post' ), // Post type
    'context'       => 'normal',
    'priority'      => 'high',
    'show_names'    => true
) ); 

$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'       => __( 'Embed Code', 'ttt' ),
    'id'         => $prefix . 'embed_code',
    'type'       => 'textarea',        
    'sanitization_cb' => false,      
) );
```

Here is how I use it the field.

```
$embed_code = get_post_meta($id, 'ttt_embed_code', true )
```